# Android upload file to server using php

Tags: java, php, android

Hello am trying to upload a file from external storage of android phone to the url in the variable upLoadServerUri as below.

```
final String upLoadServerUri = "http://www.www.com/UploadToServer.php";
URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

// Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

// create a buffer of  maximum size
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// read file and write it into form...
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0) {

    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
    Log.d("Inside ByteRead", "Reading");
}

// send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();


fileInputStream.close();
dos.flush();
dos.close();
```

The code below is being used in the UploadToServer.php file which is the destination url file in the java code above. I don't have knowledge on php end so can you advise me if below code would be able to store data when we trigger a file to it based on the java code above. Thanks.

```
<?php
// Where the file is going to be placed
$target_path = "recorded/";

/* Add the original filename to our target path.
Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']).
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
    echo "target_path: " .$target_path;
}
?>
```

Comment: The php script is echoing info to your Android app. This is done to communicate. You are not reading these echos in your Android app. So you do not know what happened in the script.

Comment: The php script looks ok. But your android code is missing the part to read the echos.

Comment: Strange that you did not tell us if you could upload a file. Strange that you did not report how your Android code flowed. Code and message.

Comment: @greenapps thanks for the response. Can you tell me if the above php code can accept and store incoming files..?

Comment: You should start reacting to all i said.

Answer (score 0):

Please try retrofit. Its simple and easy. Read this tutorial. [Upload Files to Server](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server)

Comment: I have issue with the php code. I feel android code is fine.